# ms-access 2003 countif in a report

Tags: ms-access-2003

I have a report that displays all office employees.  I am trying to give a summary of employee by type in the foother of the report and I receive an #Error as a result.

```
Report Detail
Name    DOH    UserID    Position

Page Footer
Text Box with "=Count(IIf([Position] Like "CS",0))"
I have also tried "=Count(IIf([Position]="CS",0))"
```

Both Return #Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through Trial and error I found the following to work

```
=Count(IIf([Position]="CS",1,0))
```